# What is the difference between "reinigen" and "bereinigen"?

Tags: meaning, verb-usage, verb-choice

I can say

> Ich möchte mein Zimmer reinigen

but I can also say

> Ich möchte mein Zimmer bereinigen

What is the difference?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary already for the difference between "reinigen" und "bereinigen" ?

Answer (score 4):

> bereinigen

Sort out something that's upset you, sort out ("Settle an argument")

> reinigen

Remove dirt, stains or similar from something (clean something, clean up)

**Explain:**

But you can't say "*... mein Zimmer bereinigen*" (as far as I know). You can clean (*reinigen*) your room, or clean up (*aufräumen*) the room.

In German duden "*bereinigen*" is defined as follows:

- einen Streitfall bereinigen (schlichten)
- eine bereinigte (korrigierte) Ausgabe eines Buches
- die Rechnung haben wir um Sondereffekte bereinigt (wir haben die Sondereffekte herausgerechnet)

So "*bereinigen*" has nothing to do with cleaning or similar.

Comment: Please consider a link to Duden's entry to give room for further reading. Including Duden's content was the more important part of the reference.

Comment: I insist that you cannot say "mein Zimmer bereinigen" - well, in Germany you can, doing exactly the definition you brought. Using it I could bereinige mein Zimmer um das Spielzeug. I see no problem in it. It is more figurativly, though.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm *"Mein Zimmer von Spielzeug bereinigen."*

Comment: Yes of course, but you can't say, "Ich möchte mein Zimmer bereinigen". There is something missing... But "Das Zimmer von unnötigen Sachen bereinigen" or how @akuzminykh said,  is really correctly. But I never said that this isn't correct! i just say, that you can't "bereinigen" your room, you can "bereinigen" your room from anything, but you can't "bereinigen" your room!!!!!!!

Comment: Okay, that part I misunderstood in your answer. I just am unable to read the part where you explain that if I want to bereinige mein Zimmer that I need an object attached to the sentence. I just read that it is to sort sth out and that I can't use it with mein Zimmer bereinigen. And from the meaning I additionally insist that it has nothing to do with cleaning or similiar [like clean up] - as it has: removing objects (rather than infrastructure) tends to clean up as well.

Comment: Just one comment: _ein Zimmer bereinigen_ is a sort of clumsy German sometimes talked by 'Ausländer', whether completed by any (prepositional)  object or not. I am German and by no means I can imagine a functional context for the expression. (I didn't try hard drugs, though). Any discussion about it is like a discussion about the appropriateness of the genus of a given German noun. So I don't know what you are talking about here. For me, it's just wrong. Would you say analogously 'den Tisch vom Geschirr bereinigt?' The difference is: 'reinigen' is concrete, 'bereinigen' ist abstract. So, ...

Comment: ... how do you want to 'bereinigen' a room in an abstract way?